# How to properly make a SignUp

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am currently learning React Native and while I already have a lot of Stuff built for my app, there is still one thing that always stumps me and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I googled and looked through the docs from react, react-native and react-navigation but couldn't find an answer.

**The Problem**
Today I revisited my SignUp page and wanted to split it up in multiple Forms so the User does not have to scroll to answer every question.

So I am not sure if I should

1. use a StackNavigator and pass an every increasing amount of props to the next Component

or,

2. What I am currently doing is, have one gigantic Component and render one form at a time and manage everything in one Component.

Obviously the Second Choice is really messy although I have every form in another File. But I feel I would be repeating myself A LOT if used Number 1 (especially since I use typescript).

Is there another option ? Some sort of HOC perhaps ? I am really at a loss.

I thought that I sort of can have one Component that manage the SignUp Process and navigates (renders) the next Form neatly but what I have now is not neatly AT ALL.

Hope you guys can help me or direct me to some nice Ressource

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are currently doing is a better choice than the first one. Rendering Different Forms(Component) with respect to the currentStep in the main form(Component) and not everything has to be done in the main form. The main form just needs to have state updated with respect to the operations done in the form currently being displayed.

Comment: I just thought about that maybe I should do solution 1 but instead of passing everything as props, I create a redux state for the signup and use it across the SignUp stack. Advantage being I dont have to pass an increasing amount of props forwards and backwards. What do you think ? Even when the User completely leaves, I could repopulate it with redux-persist

Comment: You can use redux with both approaches. I still think the second approach is better. You can choose whatever you want